# Call controller method after validation in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

Here is a code from Lumen official documentaion

```
$router->post('/user', function (Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
    ]);

    // Store User...
 });
```

But how I can call controller method after validation ? Docs says nothing about that, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

In this case ur not passing a controller as parameter to the route, your passing a closure so technically that's your logic (if you want to use controller check code below)

**but i assume this is what you should do**

```
$router->post('/user','MyController@myMethod');
```

**Then in your controller**

```
public function myMethod(Request $request){
   $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
    ]);

   // You do whatever floats your boat here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm already done it at controller, but wondering, why authors put such code in the officicial docs :(

Comment: because it's about validation not about controllers i assume, also it's documented in the laravel docs i assume

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov what is your contribution by sharing the link? he's code is copied from there already and he is asking something else.